# Where to find printed version of The Busy Coders Guide to Android Development

Tags: android

The Busy Coders Guide to Android Development is a really good book imho. I would like to have a printed version of it, on Amazon it is sold al 199$ (???). Is there any way to get it in printing at a reasonable price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, Mark Murphy's great eBook is published by Apress as "Beginning Android 3"

[http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Android-3-Mark-Murphy/dp/1430232978/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1323784195&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232978)

( You can compare the Table of Contents of the eBook here : http://commonsware.com/Android/ )

Comment: This is correct. Bear in mind that I am not involved with any further editions from Apress, though.